# Filtering an array of objects based on another array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, compare

I have an array of messages like

```
oldMessages = [ {id:1,message:'message_A'} , {id:2,message:'message_B'} ]
```

and another array as

```
newMessages = [ {id:1,message:'message_A'} , {id:2,message:'message_B'} , {id:3,message:'message_C'} ]
```

How do I get only the part `{id:3,message:'message_c'}` by comparing `oldMessages` with `newMessages`? 
I must compare them based on their id only.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Can you post some code of what have you tried, please?

Comment: I wanted to, but my code is messed up, so I posted above example, any help on it is very much appreciated, thank you

Comment: And what have you investigated about it ???

Comment: a few things about includes and filter in js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this using array [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method like:

```js
const oldMessages = [ {id:1,message:'message_A'} , {id:2,message:'message_B'} ]
const newMessages = [ {id:1,message:'message_A'},{id:2,message:'message_B'} , {id:3,message:'message_C'} ]
const data = newMessages.find(r=> !oldMessages.map(x=>x.id).includes(r.id))

console.log( data )
```